# generic base class where T is other generic base class

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract generic class:

```
public abstract class SomeBaseClass<U,V>
{
}
```

I want to create other generic class:

```
public abstract class SomeOtherBaseClass<T1, T2> where T1 : SomeBaseClass<U,V>
{
    private readonly T1 _someBaseClass;

    public SomeOtherBaseClass(T1 someBaseClass)
    {
        _someBaseClass = someBaseClass;
    }
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public abstract class SomeOtherBaseClass<T1, T2, U, V>
    where T1 : SomeBaseClass<U, V>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may give you what you need:

```
public abstract class SomeOtherBaseClass<U, V, T2> 
{
    private readonly SomeBaseClass<U, V> _someBaseClass;

    public SomeOtherBaseClass(SomeBaseClass<U, V> someBaseClass)
    {
        _someBaseClass = someBaseClass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class SomeOtherBaseClass<T1, T2> where T1 : SomeBaseClass<T1,T2>
```

Comment: `SomeBaseClass` did not define it's first type argument `U` to be reflexive, so this is not correct.  Furthermore, the OP gave no indication that the type arguments for the two base classes were related.